Подходит ли здесь "будь то" стилистически?
А я вновь с медицинским текстом)
"Эти изменения могут произойти в любой момент нашей жизни, будь то во время развития плода в утробе матери или после рождения".
По-моему, звучит как-то ни к селу ни к городу. Как думаете вы?

Это сочетание соответствует книжному стилю, поэтому корректно и в этом тексте:
Эти изменения могут произойти в любой момент нашей жизни, будь то во время развития плода в утробе матери или после рождения.
ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Русский орфографический словарь: будь то... или… (будет ли это тем или другим)
Значение: независимо от того, будет ли это...
Карта слов
Будь то — соединительные слова, употр. перед разделительным перечислением ряда слов, в знач.: все равно кто, что. Красная армия никогда не будет воевать против всего народа, будь то поляки, англичане, румыны или французы.
Предложения со словосочетанием «будь то во время»
Никто не знает, могут ли люди успешно размножаться в космосе, будь то во время космического полёта или непосредственно на другой планете.
Except, no one really knows if humans can successfully reproduce in space, whether that's during spaceflight or on another planet.
